# How to avoid password when using sudo in gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a private docker repository where i store my build images.
I did copy my registry certificates and updated my /etc/hosts file to authenticate registry from my local machine.

I could login to registry with `'sudo docker login -u xxx -p xxx registry-name:port'`

But when i try same docker login command from gitlab-ci stage, it is failing with this error:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.

This is how i'm trying to achieve this.

```
ssh manohara@${DEPLOY_SERVER_IP} "sudo docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}"
```

I also tried adding this gitlab-runner `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` at the bottom of /etc/sudoers file, but no luck
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I tried adding this  
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
at the bottom of /etc/sudoers file, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281742/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified) you can use

```
ssh -t remotehost "sudo ./binary"
```

The -t allocates a pseudo-tty.

Or in your example:

```
ssh -t manohara@${DEPLOY_SERVER_IP} "sudo docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}"
```