# no tty present and no askpass program specified in gitlab-ci ssh mode

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
before_script:
  - sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
  - pip install fabric

staging:
  type: deploy
  script:
    - fab -f fab_crawler start:test  
  only:
    - test

production:
  type: deploy
  script: 
    - fab -f fab_crawler start:dev
  only:
    - master
```

and this is my gitlab-runner config file in `/etc/gitlab-runner`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "xxx"
  url = "xxx"
  token = "xxx"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "root"
    host = "80.xxx.xxx.xx6"
    port = "xxxx"
    identity_file = "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

when I push something to the test branch, in the jobs I get this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.6.0 (f100a208)
  on xxx XMdAz8un
Using Shell executor...
Running on gitlab-runner...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at eaffd0f Remove unwanted functions
Checking out eaffd0f2 as test...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I also add `gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to the bottom of the `/etc/sudoers` file but it didnt work [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537149/how-to-avoid-password-when-using-sudo-in-gitlab-ci-yml) question also has this problem.
Is this wierd that I use a `ssh` runner in config file but gitlab-ci executor says `Using Shell executor...`?

Answer (score 2):

For me the trick was to use visudo to add the line `gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
Just using vi didnt work for whatever reasons.

I found details about visudo and this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error#24107529)

Answer (score 2):

add these 2 commands in your `/etc/sudoers`

```
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your identity file (/root/.ssh/id_rsa) password protected?

Comment: No, when I used ssh-keygen for generating a new `rsa`, I ignored the password section and press enter

Answer (score 0):

ah for ssh executor just for run script on target host, it cant run command like apt install etc.

its write on docs gitlab ci ssh executor https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ssh.html

> The SSH executor supports only scripts generated in Bash and the caching feature is currently not supported.

maybe its help.